# Why is event.target.files[0].name showing error in my code?

Tags: javascript, filenames, reader

I have this JS code (given below) which converts a JSON file to XML file. Everything works perfectly (I get the contents of the file), but now I want to fetch the filename of the uploaded file.

```
function onChange(event) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (event)=>{
          let data = JSON.parse(event.target.result);
          $("#jsonArea").val(event.target.result);
          var finalXML = '<root>' + x2js.json2xml_str($.parseJSON(event.target.result)) + '</root>';
          var finalName = event.target.files[0].name; //setting it here
          $("#xmlArea").val(finalXML);

          finalXML = finalXML.split('FORM3CA').join('FORM3CB');
          finalXML = finalXML.split('F3CA').join('F3CB');
          finalXML = finalXML.split('<CreationInfo>')[0] + '<CreationInfo><SWVersionNo>1.0</SWVersionNo><SWCreatedBy>SW20000</SWCreatedBy><JSONCreatedBy>SW20000</JSONCreatedBy><JSONCreationDate>2021-11-21</JSONCreationDate><IntermediaryCity>311</IntermediaryCity></CreationInfo>' + finalXML.split('</CreationInfo>')[1]
          finalXML = finalXML.split('I_We1').join('I_We');
          
          console.log(finalName); //here
        }
        reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);
    }
 
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', onChange);
```

I was suggested to use `event.target.files[0].name` in order to get the filename of the uploaded file (by @HeryKurniawan in comments of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70117084/17056122) post). But, when I try to `console.log()`the `finalName` variable (as you can see in above code), it shows me this error -

[image]

What is wrong in my code? I have also tried using `event.target.file.name` & `event.target.file[0].name`, but that doesn't work either. Kindly guide... Thanks! :)

Comment: Because files[0] is undefined. You probably don't have any file selected.

Comment: Have you tried naming your `event` from both events differently? Because now you try to access `event.target.files[0].name` of _FileReader_ and it does not have that property

Comment: Hi @GoldenretriverYT - the error I posted only comes after I select the file. Here's a more detailed screenshot - https://i.ibb.co/xgF75Vd/image.png ; Kindly have a look :)

Comment: Hi @Justinas - Thanks for replying, but unfortunately I don't know what that means - can you provide an example/link a relevant post here? That would be of great help... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are using two events that has same name `event` and try to use it is same scope:

```js
$("#jsonArea").val(event.target.result); // Here is event from FileReader.onload
var finalName = event.target.files[0].name; // Here you try to use event from onChange
```

So you face names overwrite, that's why you get error.

To solve it, use different names:

```js
    function onChange(event) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (frEvent)=>{
          let data = JSON.parse(frEvent.target.result);
          $("#jsonArea").val(frEvent.target.result);
          var finalXML = '<root>' + x2js.json2xml_str($.parseJSON(frEvent.target.result)) + '</root>';
          var finalName = frEvent.target.fileName; //setting it here
          $("#xmlArea").val(finalXML);

          finalXML = finalXML.split('FORM3CA').join('FORM3CB');
          finalXML = finalXML.split('F3CA').join('F3CB');
          finalXML = finalXML.split('<CreationInfo>')[0] + '<CreationInfo><SWVersionNo>1.0</SWVersionNo><SWCreatedBy>SW20000</SWCreatedBy><JSONCreatedBy>SW20000</JSONCreatedBy><JSONCreationDate>2021-11-21</JSONCreationDate><IntermediaryCity>311</IntermediaryCity></CreationInfo>' + finalXML.split('</CreationInfo>')[1]
          finalXML = finalXML.split('I_We1').join('I_We');
          
          console.log(finalName); //here
        }

        reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);
    }
 
    document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', onChange);
```

Answer (score 0):

*First of all, thank you everyone who answered/commented.*

---

I got my desired result by doing this -

`finalName = document.getElementById('file').value`

Thanks a lot! :)